# Facebook: refresh long-lived token from native desktop app

Tags: facebook, access-token

after searching and reading the [official docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending) on extending tokens I don't get a clear pciture if there's a better way to refresh long-lived access tokens from a native desktop app than prompting the user to login and authorize url again. This call is not allowed for dektop apps:

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
client_id={app-id}&
client_secret={app-secret}&
fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

So the only choice I find now is detect if token is about to expire and when true redirect user to login page to re-authorize my app, not very comfortable, do you know of any other method?

Answer (score 2):

According to your question you want to refresh long lived token.The service you want to hit is to get long lived from short lived token which you have got from authentication flow, rather than refreshing existing long lived token

You can generate a new long-lived token by sending the person back to the login flow used by your web app - note that the person will not actually need to login again, they have already authorized your app, so they will immediately redirect back to your app from the login flow with a refreshed token.

After doing the above you will obtain a new short-lived token and then you need to perform the same exchange for a long-lived token.

Refer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens to get details in depth